# Asp.net Core Website icons are missing hosting in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I converted my Asp.net web core and Api core using docker and while i need both containers at the same time, i used docker-compose. Everything works fine but some Icons are not displayed on the web page.
When I run the same Web App on IIS express, all icons are displayed fine. I don't get what could be the problem. In exact same Icons folder, some icons are displayed when i host as docker container and some not. They appear as 404 not found. My code is surely fine as IIS express display the icons.
I searched all over but i cant find anyone else having same problem. I am new in docker. So not sure how to inspect that situation?
I am using Docker windows running as Linux Container.

DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myAppWebCore/myAppWebCore.csproj", "myAppWebCore/"]
COPY ["myApp.Data/myApp.Data.csproj", "myApp.Data/"]
RUN dotnet restore "myAppWebCore/myAppWebCore.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myAppWebCore"
RUN dotnet build "myAppWebCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myAppWebCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myAppWebCore.dll"]
```

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myAppcoreapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myappcoreapi
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: myAppCoreApi/Dockerfile 
    networks: 
      - backend
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:     
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development     
    environment:  
      FLASK_ENV: Development
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "5001:443"  
  myAppwebcore:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myappwebcore
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: myAppWebCore/Dockerfile
    networks: 
      - backend
```

networks:
backend:
driver: "bridge"

EDIT:

I have just checked the logs in Docker Windows for my container. And icons those are fine displayed. there is log like below.
But there is not "Sending File" log for the ones not displayed. It seems like when I deploy those Icons are not deployed to docker.

```
Sending file. Request path: '/images/google-play-badge.svg'. Physical path: '/app/wwwroot/images/google-play-badge.svg'
```

Comment: Could you share your docker file and docker-compose file?

Comment: @Kaan just updated my quesiton